# How to use init() in multiple x-data spreads?

Tags: alpine.js

I've split up my methods into two functions in a separate JS file. Both parts need `x-init`, but only the second part's `init()` method is triggered:

```html
<div
    x-data="{
        ...part1(),
        ...part2(),
    }">
    <p>Check the console</p>
</div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('part1', () => ({
        init(){
            // Not triggered
            console.log("Part 1 init");
        }
    })
)});

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('part2', () => ({
        init(){
            console.log("Part 2 init");
        }
    })
)});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/kslstn/pen/popwpKG?editors=1111)

Can we have 2 `init()`s in one `x-data`?

Comment: Here's my take on it more than a year later. I feel Ryan Kennedy below is touching on something important with his first option. The reason I wanted to split up my x-data on one component was sloppy separation of functionality. I'm now making smaller x-data functions, which makes it easier to see what methods are used where for what. Another reason I used spreads was to create variants of features. I found that I can often achieve the same result by defining properties differently for each variant instead: `x-data="part1({option1: 'a', option2: 'b'}"`.

Comment: Moreover, I used to include helper functions in some of the parts. But these didn't have to be Alpine components. I now find it more useful to separate these generic functions, so they can be used even if/where I don't use Alpine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution here, if it's an option, would be to use two separate
DOM elements:

```
<div x-data="part1()">
  <div x-data="part2()">
    <p>Check the console</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I understand this might not be desirable.

Due to the way the [object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) works, your init method from `part1` is being overwritten with the one from `part2` before AlpineJS even sees it. If you plan to do a lot of this type of merged data object, you might consider writing a helper such as:

```
Alpine.magic('merge', (...inputs) => inputs.reduce((state, next) => {
  const prevInit = typeof state.init === 'function' ? state.init : () => {};
  return {
    ...state,
    ...next,
    init() {
      prevInit.call(this);
      next.init.call(this);
    }
  };
}, {});


<div x-data="$merge(part1(), part2())">...</div>
```

Depending on what you're doing, you might consider writing this as a directive instead. At least as of Alpine v3, it's possible to add multiple `x-init` directives as long as they're namespaced. For example:

```
<span x-init.foo="console.log('foo')" x-init.bar="console.log('bar')"></span>
```

You would implement this as:

```
document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
  Alpine.directive('part1', (el, {expression}) => {
    Alpine.bind(el, {
      ['x-init.part1']() {
        console.log('part 1 init');
      }
    })
  });
  Alpine.directive('part2', (el, {expression}) => {
    Alpine.bind(el, {
      ['x-init.part2']() {
        console.log('part 2 init');
      }
    })
  });
});
```

You might end up with issues using this approach, though. In general simpler is better.